# getEntity().getContent() method of HttpResponse only have </ERROR>

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I was trying to get a xml response  through web service call by using Default httpClient but not able do so
                as error message    coming in response.getEntity().getContent().
                line String veraible always comming  though my response code 200 comming.
        DefaultHttp client object is created from another method
        Here is my code--

```
            try {
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(tmsURL);
            post.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(METHOD_PARAM, method));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(XML_PARAM, xml));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity_st=new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8");
            post.setEntity(entity_st);


                            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post,localcontext);


                            responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                            if (responseCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                                 BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                                  String line = "";
                                  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                                    System.out.println(line);
                                  }
            }
} catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                logger.info("Exception occured in httpClientSendRequest() : "
                        + printStackTrace(e));
                result = buildXmlErrorMessage("", e.getMessage(), "");
            } finally {
                // post.releaseConnection();
            }

    please help me if anybody have any solution to solve the issue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try 
 {  

                         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("url");

                         static_class.str_IpAddress=getLocalIpAddress();

                        // Add your data
                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserName", "str_user_name"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", "str_password"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IpAddress", "str_IpAddress"));
                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                        // Execute HTTP Post Request
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);     
                      //  Log.w("response message....",""+responseText);
                        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseText.getBytes());
                        doc = db.parse(is);
                        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Response");
                        Node node = nodeList.item(0);                           
                        Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;


                        NodeList toList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("ResponseMessage");
                        Element nameElement = (Element) toList.item(0);
                        toList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
                        String str_welcome_message=""+((Node) toList.item(0)).getNodeValue();



                     catch(Exception e)
                     {

                         Log.w("DocumentBuilderFactory",""+e);
                     }
```

Comment: from  String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity); getting value for responseText =<ERROR/>

Comment: do you have any idea why <ERROR/> is always coming in responseText String object.

Comment: @rand i have already test this code it's run properly .....you have to say <ERROR> return in String responseText means your request send successfully...maybe problem in number of nameValuePairs is different......first you have to check this url run directly browser and show value of responce...

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working fine. The problem lies with your POST request, you may want to check the parameters.

Comment: is there any problem with DefaultHttpClient object creation??

Comment: A simple DefaultHttpClient object as instantiated by Parag should do. I hope I understand the problem well, your are not getting an exception but in the response string returned there is an error message. right?